# Wavelets plot: changing x-, y- axis, and color plot

Tags: plot, colorbar, wavelet, biwavelet

I have a code that I am working on for hourly dataset and want to display a proper wavelet plot but I am having trouble adjusting it to my liking. I want to change the x-, y- axis and put up a color bar.  I have successfully changed the x-axis, however, that is only when color bar is not activated.  If it is, then I cannot change the x-axis.  In addition, I haven't found a successful way to change the y-axis to have more values in between then what is automatically generated.  Thank you in advance for your help

```
    library(biwavelet) # used for wavelets

    n <- 141696
    d <- data.frame(1:n, round(runif(n, 38, 100),2))

    # X-Axis for plotting
    TIME1 <- as.POSIXlt("2000-01-01 00:00:00 PST", format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    TIME2 <- as.POSIXlt("2016-02-29 23:00:00 PST", format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    LABELS <- seq(from = TIME1, to = TIME2, by = "3 months")
    xAxis <- seq(from = TIME1, to = TIME2, by = "hour")
    Location <-NA
    for (i in 1:length(LABELS)) { Location[i] <- which(LABELS[i] == xAxis) }
    LABELS <- format(LABELS, "%b %Y")

    # Wavelet
    WAV <- wt(d)
```

This has the correct x-axis but does not display the color bar since I did not put `plot.cb = TRUE` in the plot as an argument.

```
    # PLOT (Has no legend but correct x-axis)
    par(oma=c(0, 0, 0, 1), mar=c(5, 4, 4, 5) + 0.1)
    plot(WAV, type="power.corr.norm", main="Bias-corrected wavelet power ", ylab="Period(hourly)", xlab="Time", lwd.sig=1, xaxt='n')
    axis(side = 1, at = Location, labels = LABELS, tick = TRUE, las = 2)
```

[No Color Bar, correct x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyWV7.jpg)

This displays the color bar but does not have the proper x-axis labeled.

```
    # PLOT (Has legend but no x-axis)
    par(oma=c(0, 0, 0, 1), mar=c(5, 4, 4, 5) + 0.1)
    plot(WAV, type="power.corr.norm", main="Bias-corrected wavelet power ", ylab="Period(hourly)", xlab="Time", lwd.sig=1, xaxt='n', plot.cb=TRUE)
    axis(side = 1, at = Location, labels = LABELS, tick = TRUE, las = 2)
```

[No x-axis, but color bar present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7vfF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Get into the function itself by typing `plot.biwavelet`, copy it to your script editor and edit the function, give it a new name such as `myplot`, edit it then run `myplot` instead of `plot.biwavelet`. You can change whatever you want within the `plot.biwavelet` function. For example, to increase the number of xlim labels, just do: `locs <- pretty(range(xlim), n = 10)`. Currently, `n=5`.