# biwavelet package: "cex.axis" not working in plot.biwavelet(); A bug?

Tags: r, plot, biwavelet

I am using `biwavelet` package to conduct wavelet analysis. However, when I want to adjust the label size for axis using `cex.axis`, the label size does not changed. On the other hand, `cex.lab` and `cex.main` are working well. Is this a bug? The following gives a reproducible example.

```
library(biwavelet)
t1 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
t2 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
# Continuous wavelet transform
wt.t1 <- wt(t1)
par(oma = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0), mar = c(4, 2, 2, 4))
plot(wt.t1,plot.cb = T,plot.phase = T,type = 'power.norm',
 xlab = 'Time(year)',ylab = 'Period(year)',mgp=c(2,1,0),
 main='Winter station 1',cex.main=0.8,cex.lab=0.8,cex.axis=0.8)
```

**Edit**

There was a previous question on this site a month ago: [Wavelets plot: changing x-, y- axis, and color plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37305790/4891738), but not solved. Any help this time? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yeah, it is a bug. Here is patched version: my.plot.biwavelet()**

This version accepts argument `cex.axis` (defaults to 1), and you can change it when needed. I will briefly explain to you what the problem is, in the "explanation" section in the end.

```
my.plot.biwavelet <- function (x, ncol = 64, fill.cols = NULL, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Period", 
    tol = 1, plot.cb = FALSE, plot.phase = FALSE, type = "power.corr.norm", 
    plot.coi = TRUE, lwd.coi = 1, col.coi = "white", lty.coi = 1, 
    alpha.coi = 0.5, plot.sig = TRUE, lwd.sig = 4, col.sig = "black", 
    lty.sig = 1, bw = FALSE, legend.loc = NULL, legend.horiz = FALSE, 
    arrow.len = min(par()$pin[2]/30, par()$pin[1]/40), arrow.lwd = arrow.len * 
        0.3, arrow.cutoff = 0.9, arrow.col = "black", xlim = NULL, 
    ylim = NULL, zlim = NULL, xaxt = "s", yaxt = "s", form = "%Y", cex.axis = 1,
    ...)  {
         if (is.null(fill.cols)) {
             if (bw) {
                fill.cols <- c("black", "white")
            }
            else {
                fill.cols <- c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", 
                  "cyan", "#7FFF7F", "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", 
                  "#7F0000")
            }
        }
        col.pal <- colorRampPalette(fill.cols)
        fill.colors <- col.pal(ncol)
        types <- c("power.corr.norm", "power.corr", "power.norm", 
            "power", "wavelet", "phase")
        type <- match.arg(tolower(type), types)
        if (type == "power.corr" | type == "power.corr.norm") {
            if (x$type == "wtc" | x$type == "xwt") {
                x$power <- x$power.corr
                x$wave <- x$wave.corr
            }
            else {
                x$power <- x$power.corr
            }
        }
         if (type == "power.norm" | type == "power.corr.norm") {
            if (x$type == "xwt") {
                zvals <- log2(x$power)/(x$d1.sigma * x$d2.sigma)
                if (is.null(zlim)) {
                   zlim <- range(c(-1, 1) * max(zvals))
                }
                zvals[zvals < zlim[1]] <- zlim[1]
                locs <- pretty(range(zlim), n = 5)
                leg.lab <- 2^locs
            }
            else if (x$type == "wtc" | x$type == "pwtc") {
                zvals <- x$rsq
                zvals[!is.finite(zvals)] <- NA
                if (is.null(zlim)) {
                  zlim <- range(zvals, na.rm = TRUE)
                }
                zvals[zvals < zlim[1]] <- zlim[1]
                locs <- pretty(range(zlim), n = 5)
                leg.lab <- locs
            }
            else {
                zvals <- log2(abs(x$power/x$sigma2))
                if (is.null(zlim)) {
                  zlim <- range(c(-1, 1) * max(zvals))
                }
                zvals[zvals < zlim[1]] <- zlim[1]
                locs <- pretty(range(zlim), n = 5)
                leg.lab <- 2^locs
            }
        }
        else if (type == "power" | type == "power.corr") {
            zvals <- log2(x$power)
            if (is.null(zlim)) {
                zlim <- range(c(-1, 1) * max(zvals))
            }
            zvals[zvals < zlim[1]] <- zlim[1]
            locs <- pretty(range(zlim), n = 5)
            leg.lab <- 2^locs
        }
        else if (type == "wavelet") {
            zvals <- (Re(x$wave))
            if (is.null(zlim)) {
                zlim <- range(zvals)
            }
            locs <- pretty(range(zlim), n = 5)
            leg.lab <- locs
        }
        else if (type == "phase") {
            zvals <- x$phase
            if (is.null(zlim)) {
                zlim <- c(-pi, pi)
            }
            locs <- pretty(range(zlim), n = 5)
            leg.lab <- locs
        }
        if (is.null(xlim)) {
            xlim <- range(x$t)
        }
        yvals <- log2(x$period)
        if (is.null(ylim)) {
            ylim <- range(yvals)
        }
        else {
             ylim <- log2(ylim)
        }
        image(x$t, yvals, t(zvals), zlim = zlim, xlim = xlim, 
             ylim = rev(ylim), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, yaxt = "n", 
             xaxt = "n", col = fill.colors, ...)
        box()
         if (class(x$xaxis)[1] == "Date" | class(x$xaxis)[1] == 
              "POSIXct") {
             if (xaxt != "n") {
                  xlocs <- pretty(x$t) + 1
                 axis(side = 1, at = xlocs, labels = format(x$xaxis[xlocs], 
                   form))
             }
          }
         else {
              if (xaxt != "n") {
                xlocs <- axTicks(1)
                axis(side = 1, at = xlocs, cex.axis = cex.axis)
             }
        }
        if (yaxt != "n") {
            axis.locs <- axTicks(2)
            yticklab <- format(2^axis.locs, dig = 1)
            axis(2, at = axis.locs, labels = yticklab, cex.axis = cex.axis)
         }
         if (plot.coi) {
             polygon(x = c(x$t, rev(x$t)), lty = lty.coi, lwd = lwd.coi, 
                  y = c(log2(x$coi), rep(max(log2(x$coi), na.rm = TRUE), 
                  length(x$coi))), col = adjustcolor(col.coi, 
                  alpha.f = alpha.coi), border = col.coi)
         }
         if (plot.sig & length(x$signif) > 1) {
             if (x$type %in% c("wt", "xwt")) {
                 contour(x$t, yvals, t(x$signif), level = tol, 
                  col = col.sig, lwd = lwd.sig, add = TRUE, drawlabels = FALSE)
              }
             else {
                 tmp <- x$rsq/x$signif
                 contour(x$t, yvals, t(tmp), level = tol, col = col.sig, 
                   lwd = lwd.sig, add = TRUE, drawlabels = FALSE)
             }
         }
         if (plot.phase) {
             a <- x$phase
             locs.phases <- which(zvals < quantile(zvals, arrow.cutoff))
             a[locs.phases] <- NA
              phase.plot(x$t, log2(x$period), a, arrow.len = arrow.len, 
                 arrow.lwd = arrow.lwd, arrow.col = arrow.col)
         }
          box()
          if (plot.cb) {
              fields::image.plot(x$t, yvals, t(zvals), zlim = zlim, ylim = rev(range(yvals)), 
                  xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, col = fill.colors, 
                 smallplot = legend.loc, horizontal = legend.horiz, 
                legend.only = TRUE, axis.args = list(at = locs, 
                    labels = format(leg.lab, dig = 2)), xpd = NA)
        }
    }
```

**Test**

```
library(biwavelet)
t1 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
t2 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
# Continuous wavelet transform
wt.t1 <- wt(t1)
par(oma = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0), mar = c(4, 2, 2, 4))
my.plot.biwavelet(wt.t1,plot.cb = T,plot.phase = T,type = 'power.norm',
   xlab = 'Time(year)',ylab = 'Period(year)',mgp=c(2,1,0),
   main='Winter station 1',cex.main=0.8,cex.lab=0.8,cex.axis=0.8)
```

As expected, it is working.

[image: nice]

---

**Explanation**

In `plot.biwavelet()`, why passing `cex.axis` via `...` does not work?

`plot.biwavelet()` generates the your final plot mainly in 3 stages:

1. `image(..., xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")` for generating basic plot;
2. `axis(1, at = atTicks(1)); axis(2, at = atTicks(2))` for adding axis;
3. `fields::image.plot()`  for displaying colour legend strip.

Now, although this function takes `...`, they are only fed to the first `image()` call, while the following `axis()`, *(including `polygon(), contour()`, `phase.plot()`)* and `image.plot()` take none from `...`. When later calling `axis()`, no flexible specification with respect to axis control are supported.

I guess during package development time, problem described as in: [Giving arguments from “…” argument to right function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37960698/4891738) had been encountered. Maybe the author did not realize this potential issue, leaving a bug here. My answer to that post, as well as Roland's comments, points toward a robust fix.

I am not the package author so can not decide how he will fix this. My fix is brutal, but works for you temporary need: just add the `cex.axis` argument to `axis()` call. I have reached Tarik (package author) with an email, and I believe he will give you a much better explanation and solution.

Comment: Dear Li, you are really a master in R. Thank you so much for your help and I really appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Dear Li, I am new to StackOverflow and I have just accepted your answer. I wonder how can I "vote up your answer"? Thanks.

Comment: Dear Li, I just learned how to vote up an answer on Google. Thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: Dear Li, could you explain what does "..." mean in the R code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear Li, thanks a lot. Sorry to trouble you again, but I have one more question. How can I adjust font size for the colorbar (which is the legend) in the plot? I use legend.cex=0.8 in the plot function, but R says "legend.cex is not a graphical parameter". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check the image.plot function.

Comment: Dear Li, sorry to trouble you but I do not know how to send you a message on Stackoverflow. I just post a new question about the     `biwavelet` package and could you take a look? Thank you for your help. Here is the address [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38278211/6162679)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by passing the `...` argument to `axis` in `plot.biwavelet`. Your code should now work as desired. Note that changes to `cex.axis` and other `axis` arguments will affect all three axes (x, y, z).

You can download the new version (0.20.8) of `biwavelet` from GitHub by issuing the following command at the `R` console (this assumes that you have the package `devtools` already installed): `devtools::install_github("tgouhier/biwavelet")`

Thanks for pointing out the bug!

Comment: You are amazing! It is now working. Thank you so much for your kind help.