# biwavelet package: "axis" is not working

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, biwavelet

I am using `biwavelet` package to conduct wavelet coherence analysis. When I want to set my own x ticklabel, I find `axis`is not working. The following gives a reproducible example. Thanks.

```
require(biwavelet)
t1 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
t2 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
wtc.t1t2 <- wtc(t1,t2,nrands = 10) 
plot(wtc.t1t2, plot.cb = TRUE, plot.phase = TRUE,xaxt='n')
axis(1,at = seq(10,100,10),labels = seq(1,10,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that was breaking your plot was `plot.cb = TRUE`.

In the source code for `plot.biwavelet` the author notes the following about the `plot.cb` option:

> ## Add color bar: this must happen after everything, otherwise chaos
>   ensues!

So that was the problem -- you invoked `axis()` after `plot.cb` and chaos ensued. **However**, you can manually add back the color bar using `image.plot` from the `fields` package, after having run `plot` without `plot.cb` then having added your `axis()`.

```
pacman::p_load(biwavelet,fields)
t1 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
t2 <- cbind(1:100, rnorm(100))
wtc.t1t2 <- wtc(t1,t2,nrands = 10) 
plot(wtc.t1t2, plot.phase = TRUE,xaxt='n')
axis(1,at = seq(10,100,10),labels = seq(1,20,2))
image.plot( zlim=c(0,25), legend.only=TRUE)
```

[image]

You can customize the ticks and the color bar to your liking this way!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Maybe you can help me with this one. I found a comment by the author of the package in the source code that says that if you invoke the option `plot.cb` then that *must* be the last thing you do to the plot -- if you add anything else like `axis()` the plot breaks. I'm not sure how to add `plot.cb()` after `axis()`.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I think I have an idea. Maybe we can manually add the color bar without using `plot.cb`.  Thanks for the background on this. You are probably better with plots than I am, so feel free to add an answer but I will keep hacking on it to see if I can improve my answer.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for your help. I updated it, but I only put in a generic `image.plot` legend without customizing it for his specific case. Hopefully that's good enough; if not I may try to work on it more tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I do not know how to check the source code so I do not know that adding a color bar shold be the last thing to do. Thanks a lot.